# Substitute text only between tokens (single-line)

Tags: sed

I'd like to remove spaces in strings that are between square brackets, with a single-line input.

More precisely, strings that match `\[[a-zA-Z0-9 ,]+\]` (caseless alphanum comma and space, between square brackets)

For example:

```
[ "This is a test": [a, b, c] ]
```

Should become:

```
[ "This is a test": [a,b,c] ]
```

I have tried several attempts with branching but couldn't find a syntax that worked.

For example:

```
/\[[a-zA-Z ,]\+\]/ba; :a;s/ //g;
```

but this replaces spaces on the whole line, as sed is line-based (my input is single-line).

I also tried the `;e` command which would work if the whole string was prefixed with `echo "` and suffixed with `"`, but then that would be a single/double-quote escape hell (the whole string may contain `'` and `"`).

GNU sed is welcome, but I would like to keep the dependencies minimal, so no perl unless required and no ruby, python, php...

Indeed, I know the following works perfectly, but php is a too large dependency:

```
echo preg_replace_callback(
    "/\[[a-zA-Z ,]+\]/",
    function ($m) { return str_replace(" ", "", $m[0]); },
    '{"a":{"a":{"a":"a b c"},"b":{"b":[a, b]}}}'
);
```

outputs:

```
{"a":{"a":{"a":"a b c"},"b":{"b":[a,b]}}}
```

Comment: The fact that you have square brackets nested within square brackets complicates life!

Comment: I guessed not really, since there's a regex between them to help match. But I'm far from a sed expert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### First pass — it works, but it is clumsy

Here is a solution that works with GNU and BSD `sed`:

```
sed -E \
    -e '/\[[[:alnum:] ,]+\]/ {
            s/\[([[:alnum:] ,]+)\]/^B\1^E/
            :a
            s/(^B[[:alnum:],]*) +/\1/
            t a
            s/^B/[/
            s/^E/]/
        }' \
    data
```

The appearances of `^B` and `^E` are control characters (<kbd>Control-B</kbd> and <kbd>Control-E</kbd> in the original) that aren't going to appear in the actual text.  (When first copied, I got `^B` showing as  and `^E` showing as .)

Explanation:

- `/\[[[:alnum:] ,]+\]/ {` — match lines containing square brackets with alphanumerics plus space and comma between them, and do the action sequence from `{` to the matching `}`.
- `s/\[([[:alnum:] ,]+)\]/^B\1^E/` — replace the square brackets with the control characters.
- `:a` — set a label
- `s/(^B[[:alnum:],]*) +/\1/` — replace a `^B` plus a sequence of alphanumerics or commas (which is captured) and a string of one or more spaces with just the capture.
- `t a` — if the `s///` command made a change, jump back to label `a`.
- `s/^B/[/` — replace the `^B` with open square bracket.
- `s/^E/]/` — replace the `^E` with close square bracket.
- `}` — done

The branch is necessary because normally, the `s///` operator won't rescan material that it has just substituted, whereas it is crucial that this keeps rescanning.

Given the slightly more extensive input file:

```
\[[a-zA-Z0-9 ,]+\] (caseless alphanum comma and space, between square brackets)

For example:

[ "This is a test": [a, b c] ]
[ "This is a test": [a, b, c] ]
[ "This is test 3": [  XXX,    YYY,   XXX    ] ]

Should become:

[ "This is a test": [a,bc] ]
[ "This is a test": [a,b,c] ]
[ "This is test 3": [XXX,YYY,XXX] ]
```

the script generates:

```
\[[a-zA-Z0-9 ,]+\] (caseless alphanum comma and space, between square brackets)

For example:

[ "This is a test": [a,bc] ]
[ "This is a test": [a,b,c] ]
[ "This is test 3": [XXX,YYY,XXX] ]

Should become:

[ "This is a test": [a,bc] ]
[ "This is a test": [a,b,c] ]
[ "This is test 3": [XXX,YYY,XXX] ]
```

#### Second pass — it pays to review and refine

Looking at it, the `^E` is not necessary, and maybe not the `^B` either.  The version above only deals with the first such set of square brackets on the line.  You need more sensitive detector regexes (ones that insist on at least one space in between the markers) to handle multiple such patterns on a single line.

For example:

```
sed -E \
    -e ':a
        /\[[[:alnum:],]* [[:alnum:] ,]*\]/   s/(\[[[:alnum:],]*) +/\1/
        t a' \
    data
```

Explanation:

- `:a` – set a label
- `/\[[[:alnum:],]* [[:alnum:] ,]*\]/` — if the line contains an open square bracket, zero or more alphanumeric-or-comma characters, one or more blanks, and zero or more alphanumeric-or-comma-or-blank followed by close square bracket, then …
- `s/(\[[[:alnum:],]*) +/\1/` — replace the open square and sequence of zero or more alphanumeric-or-comma characters and one or more blanks by just the non-blanks, and …
- `t a` — jump to label `a` if there was a substitution done

Given:

```
[ "This is a test": [a, b c] ]
[ "This is test 2": [a, b, c] ]
[ "This is test 3": [  XXX   ,    YYY   ,   XXX    ] ]
[ "This is test 4": [  XXX   ,    YYY   ,   XXX    ] [ 1 , 2 , 3 ] ]
[ "This is test 5": [  XXX   ,    YYY   ,   XXX    ] [ 1 , 2 , 3 ] [ abc ] [ ] ]
```

this produces:

```
["This is a test": [a,bc] ]
["This is test 2": [a,b,c] ]
["This is test 3": [XXX,YYY,XXX] ]
["This is test 4": [XXX,YYY,XXX] [1,2,3] ]
["This is test 5": [XXX,YYY,XXX] [1,2,3] [abc] [] ]
```

This is mostly equivalent to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50311573/15168) by [Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128940/beta); it could be further simplified by eliminating the match before the substitute command and modifying (slightly complicating) the substitute so it matches the work by Beta.

Comment: OK your first pass looks like this pseudo code: `if (match the square braces pattern) { replace  braces with ^B and ^E; do { remove spaces of text following a ^B } while (spaces have been removed); revert ^B and ^E back to the square braces; }`. This has greatly helped me understand the role of `t` branching, which my question was greatly about (I wanted the solution but also the understanding of sed branches).

Comment: It's not stated in the question but I'd have expected `[a, b c]` to become `[a,b c]` instead of `[a,bc]`. Seems like whats between the square brackets is comma-separated fields and so the latter would be corrupting the data.

Comment: I have edited the question, that was a typo. The input to be replaced is a comma+space separated list of tokens (a token being defined as `[A-Za-z0-9]+`).

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work:

```
sed -e ':a' -e 's#\(\[[a-zA-Z0-9,]*\) \([a-zA-Z0-9 ,]*\]\)#\1\2#
t a' filename
```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thank you for the edit; that was very careless of me.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Could you explain the line break before the `t` branching? Is it equivalent to `;` or another `-e`?

Comment: I think it is, because the following works: `sed -r ':a;s#(\[[[:alnum:],]*) ([[:alnum:] ,]*\])#\1\2#;ta'`. I like the `[:alnum:]` because it is more explicit and easier to read than the regex equivalent. Also the `-r` helps by removing the parenthesis escapes. I also like the `;` instead of the `-e` chains.

Comment: Thanks to Jonathan's explanations I think I can now read and understand your reply, which is roughly `do { replace "[pattern pattern]" to "[patternpattern]" } while (replacements were made)`, which is brilliant. Thanks!

Comment: @BenoitDuffez: I used the line break because some versions of sed -- including mine -- can't parse the `t` correctly without it. Some of the docs I've seen have it, some not. I don't know where the version boundary is.

Comment: GNU `sed` tends to be forgiving of semicolons after labels and related issues (such as appended text on the same line as the `a` command).  It is a lot easier to write one-liners for GNU `sed` than for most other versions.  I believe the standard for [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) is more rigorous and requires the line breaks as shown.